# Using markerClusterOptions with SpatialPolygons in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I am using the package Leaflet to plot around 25.000 polygons on a map. Because of this large number of polygons I want to make use of markerClusterOptions.
This is what I would like to do:

```
leaflet() %>% 
 addTiles() %>% 
 addPolygons(data=sp_polygons,
            clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

But addPolygons doesn't know clusterOptions.
What is possible, is to do the following

```
leaflet() %>% 
 addTiles() %>% 
 addMarkers(data=coordinates(sp_polygons),
            clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

But when I zoom in I only markers and not the polygons. Is there a way to use clusterOptions but still show the polygons when zooming in?

Comment: I think markerClusterOptions is only for addMarkers() or addMarkerCircles()

Answer (score 2):

To cut a long story short, you could simply create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` from the polygon data (as you did above using `coordinates`) and subsequently display points and polygons on the same map. Here is an example using the **mapview** package.

```
library(sp)
library(mapview)

## create spatial points from Switzerland administrative borders
gadmCHE_pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coordinates(gadmCHE), 
                                      data = gadmCHE@data, 
                                      proj4string = CRS(proj4string(gadmCHE)))

## display data                     
mapview(gadmCHE_pts, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) + 
  gadmCHE
```

[image: combined_image]